# Crawling data from web page with content rendered by javascript

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I am a newbie in crawling data. I want to crawl data from this site: [http://kbbi.web.id/][
[image]

I want to crawl data by input from .csv file and make crawling data work like the above picture for every csv single row and get data only from the red box, ex. mengabadi, mengabadikan, pengabadian, keabadian and save it in the new .csv file like this:

[image]

So, what can I do to crawl it (using python maybe)? And I think the web page use javascript to load/render the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `requests` and `bs4` 
sample code: (read and implement on your own, this is just for giving you a idea !)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "http://kbbi.web.id/"

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

Now, use the **inspect** tool to dig through the site, and ..
**CODE !!**

**Installing BeautifulSoup and Requests can be done with pip:**

```
$ pip install requests

$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```